# Django: which is the widget that renders the foreign key in the admin page?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Which is the widget that renders the foreign key in the admin site?

I saw that there is a widget called `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` (that print only the "+" icon) and another for the `select`, but I suppose that there is a widget that call both to render the entire field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper just [wraps](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L109) default widget, in this case Select widget.